# Opening Modules in an OCaml .mll program

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml, and I've been working on a parser (.mll file). I use StringMap somewhere in my code, and I'm unsure where & how to open the module. When I run it it says

`Error: Unbound module StringMap`

So I know I have to do `module StringMap = Map.Make(String)` but where should I put it?

Code here:

```
{ type token = EOF | Word of string }

rule token = parse (*...*)
{   
    (* use StringMap in here *)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
{
  module StringMap = Map.Make(String)

  type token = EOF | Word of string
}

rule token = parse ...
```

Note that this doesn't "open" the module `StringMap`. It just defines the module. This is good, it's best to avoid opening modules when possible.

**Update**

If you're not going to use the `StringMap` module in your lexer (which, thinking about it for a while, I decided you're probably not), you can do like this:

```
{ type token = EOF | Word of string }

rule token = parse ...

{
    module StringMap = Map.Make(String)

    ... any other code ...
}
```

**Update 2**

Here is a full working example. I hope it's not overkill; I don't want to take the fun out of it.

```
{ }

rule scan = parse
  | '\n'        { scan lexbuf }
  | _ as c      { Some c }
  | eof         { None }

{
  module CharMap = Map.Make(Char)

  let main () =
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
    let rec loop map =
        match scan lexbuf with
        | Some c ->
            let map' =
                if CharMap.mem c map then
                    CharMap.add c (CharMap.find c map + 1) map
                else
                    CharMap.add c 1 map
            in
            loop map'
        | None -> map
    in
    let m = loop CharMap.empty in
    CharMap.iter (fun c ct -> Printf.printf "%c %d\n" c ct) m

  let () = main ()
}
```

It works for me:

```
$ ocamllex l.mll
4 states, 257 transitions, table size 1052 bytes
$ ocamlc -o l l.ml
$ echo swell | l
e 1
l 2
s 1
w 1
```

Comment: :') Thank you Jeffrey!!! I spent 30 minutes putting it in every place EXCEPT for that one...

Comment: I just have a quick add-on question. Jeffrey, for the bit of the code after the rule token between the two curly brackets, does that have to be 1 function?

Comment: It can be any code, not just one function. (See update.)

Comment: Hmm, I tried it out but it gives me a syntax error whenever I put a line that's not part of a function. For example, I have `module StringMap = Map.Make(String)` followed by (on a different line) `let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in //more code` and the above line throws a syntax error.

Comment: The syntax error is not because you have extra code there. It's just a syntax error in the code. You really can have any code that could appear in an .ml file. (To understand this, you could look at the generated .ml file.)